# Assigning static/same IP address to the Server everytime it logs in

Tags: c, windows, network-programming, udp, dhcp

I am working on udp server/client applicataion. Since for communicating with the server, all the clients must know the ip address and port number of the server. For this purpose, I have hard coded the ip and port number of my server to the clients so that everytime, the client connects to same ip and port number. (found the ip address of the server machine using ipconfig command.) 
But now, the problem is that I am working on DHCP network, and there is a chance that everytime sever machine is restarted, a new ip address may be assigned to it (different from the ip address known by the clients at which they will connect.) 
So, I always want the ip address hard coded at client side to be assigned to the server machine, everytime it logs in.
Is there any way to do it? I have no idea about it. Searched internet but couldn't find anything relevant. 
Looking forward to help :(

Comment: You could configure your server machine to use a static ip over the dynamic one. How this is done depends on what os the machine is running etc.

Comment: That is not a programming issue - this is a networking issue. You might be able to force using the same IP each time, but for most network configurations it is unlikely. Contact your administrator and ask for a static IP. Or buy a static IP address from your ISP.

Comment: @Dariusz, How is that a solution? How do simple chat clients work then? Most users use a DCHP network configuration.

Comment: Is there a possibility that I assign a name to my server, and using that name on client side, I find out the current IP address of the server using gethostbynaame() function?

Comment: @AnishRam : what could be solution then? :(

Comment: Chat clients usually have a server, known by hostname or IP, which they use as a hub to find addresses of other chat clients.
Using gethostbyname in your case will do nothing. There is a need for a dns-resolvable hostname or a static ip anyway.

Comment: But I am using WIFI Netwrok, and WIFI can be  from any administrator. In that case, how would I tell each administrator to assign specific/static IP to the machine which logs in as Server? :(

Comment: @AyeshaHassan If you have several networks, you cannot hardcode the IP address after all, because every network might be in its own subrange. The one uses 192.168.0.*, the other 192.168.1.*, others might use some other range or even 10.*... so you have to stay configurable nevertheless...

Comment: @Dariusz There are home routers which have their own DNS coupled with DHCP. In this case, `gethostbyname()` (or better: `getaddrinfo()`) will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your clients are local to the server, why not abandon the hard-coded server IP address, and borrow a page from [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) and use some kind of [service discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_discovery) method:

- Your clients broadcast "where is the server" message when they first come online. The server responds with "I am at IP address X.X.X.X"
- When the server comes up, it broadcasts "Server is now at IP address Y.Y.Y.Y" so that if the server crashed, the clients start using the new server.

Comment: Due to security issues, I don't want my server or the client to broadcast messages :(

Comment: Is there any way that every machine which logs in as Server sends a message to Network Administrator that "I am Server" and then administrator assigns that specific ip reserved for server to the machine from which the request came?

Comment: @Ayesha Hassan: re: special message: I think that's what [LtWorf](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1827457/ltworf)'s solution is: hardcode the server's Mac address to a specific IP in the DHCP server. Like that but without the message part: the message is the DHCP IP address request.  Presumably your clients then would reference the server by its hostname.

Comment: @Ayesha Hassan: But your clients will already broadcast _something_, namely DHCP requests. I don't think it is possible to have a functioning networking environment without some kinds of broadcasts.

Comment: @Ayesha Hassan: Where is the security impact on broadcasting? The server's and the client's IP-addresses are visible as soon as there is a regular communication and what else would you need to send via a broadcast? If there is more information that you would need to broadcast and that is to be protected you could use encryption, so that only your server and clients can read the information (PKI). It's really stupid, but you could also spoof the sender's and receivers' addresses...

Answer (score 3):

Presuming you are working on a LAN, that's how I'd do it.

Presuming your DHCP server is configurable enough:

- Assign a static map MAC address/IP address in the dhcp server, so
  that the same machine always get the same IP (just for the server,
  not for every client).

Most entry level all in one devices with DHCP have this functionality, if not it should be quite cheap to buy a new one that has it.
If your DHCP server is a real computer, you can surely configure it to do so.

Additionally you might want to tell your clients to use a local DNS and in this local DNS server define a name for your server, so you won't have to hardcode an IP address in your clients. But the address should be located in some configuration file rather than hardcoded in any case.

I have used dnsmasq to serve as both DNS server with local names, and as DHCP server, giving the servers always the same address and pointing all the DNS requests towards itself.

This questions could be useful to find a windows alternative for dnsmasq: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709744/is-there-something-like-dnsmasq-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

By adding a reservation field in the DHCP server we can attain this.  If you are using Windows DHCP server, there is a section named 'Reservations',  there we can give the MAC address of your pc and the desired IP address. Then the server will provide the mentioned IP for you.

Answer (score 1):

With the narrow focus of a developer a DHCP reservation might be the logical step. But using a nameserver is far better. If the network itself changes or maybe the server is moved to another subnet or maybe even into anoher zone, using an IP address from a DHCP reservation fails, because the server's address changes.

You don't have any of these problems if you use a nameserver. That is what DNS is meant to be doing. Think of it as a "serviceprovider finding service" that detaches your service from the host it is running on.

And, like already suggested, you should never hardcode an IP address or DNS name or anything else that might change (even if you think it will not change) unless it is a design goal that things aren't working anymore if something changes (=not configurable).